# How can I send a command to Emacs 24 from VBA in MS Office?

Tags: emacs, vba, org-mode, emacsclient

I want to invoke commands from within MS Office application which have a direct effect on my (open) Emacs application, for example

- do a search for the currently selected text in Emacs

I wonder how I can do that.
Is there a direct way to send commands to Emacs? I'm running Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows 7 with the server options

```
;;prevent error message of unsafe server (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1313577/772434 )
(require 'server)
(and (>= emacs-major-version 23) (defun server-ensure-safe-dir (dir) "Noop" t))
(server-start)
;;(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/org/protocol/")
(require 'org-protocol)
```

and I'm using [org-protocol](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html#sec-3-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send command to Emacs (running in server mode) using `emacsclient`.

For example :

```
emacsclient --eval "(org-search-view nil """pattern""")"
```

---

If the elisp becomes too complex, you might be better of wrapping it in a file that you can load. For example :

*fun.el*

```
(defun my/search (pattern)
  (with-current-buffer "BUFFER-NAME"
     (search-forward pattern)))
```

*command-line*

```
emacsclient --load fun.el --eval '(my/search "PATTERN")'
```

Comment: thanks, that works so far. However, the output of the commnand is displayed in the terminal. How can I define the command, so that the command is executed in Emacs itself? I tried with **emacsclient --eval (org-search-view "mysearchterm")** This should create a list with search results and I'd like to have it displayed in an existing or new Emacs buffer.

Comment: The value that your form evaluates to is displayed in your terminal. However, the elisp forms are executed in Emacs itself. For exemple, `org-search-view` evaluates to `t`, which is normally not shown anywhere when you run it interactively, but is displayed in your terminal when you run it using `emacsclient`. The useful results of your search are however displayed in an Org Agenda buffer, whether you call it interactively from the command loop, or using `emacsclient`.

Comment: In your case, I think the problem rather comes from the way you call `org-search-view` non-interactively: the pattern should be the 2nd argument. See my edit and the documentation for `org-search-view`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and the suggested changes! It still does not work for me - in the command line I get _*ERROR*: End of file during parsing_ and there is no visible change in the open emacs buffers

Comment: Mmm, it looks like your emacs lisp form is incomplete. Either it is a silly copy/paste problem, or (more probably) a problem with quotes in the command line. Unfortunately, I'm no expert on the Windows command line...

Comment: quoting was not entirely correct - see my edit. Now it works fine, thanks again! :-)